Python multiprocessing taking significantly more time than sequential processing using the Multiprocessing module?
I am trying to compare the efficiency of multiprocessing module in Python by performing a CPU intensive task.
Sequential Task:
import multiprocessing
import time

v1 = [0] * 5000000
v2 = [0] * 5000000

def worker1(nums):
    global v1
    for i in range(nums):
        v1[i] = i*i
    
def worker2(nums):
    global v2
    for i in range(nums):
        v2[i] = i*i*i

start = time.time()
worker1(5000000)
worker2(5000000)
end = time.time()

print(end-start)

Time taken for sequential task - ~ 1 second
The same task using multiprocessing:
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker1(nums,v1):
    for i in range(nums):
        v1[i] = i*i
    
def worker2(nums,v2):
    for i in range(nums):
        v2[i] = i*i*i
  

v1 = multiprocessing.Array('i',5000000)
v2 = multiprocessing.Array('i',5000000)


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1, args = (5000000,v1))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2, args = (5000000,v2))

start = time.time()
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
end = time.time()

print(end-start)

Time taken for sequential task - ~ 12 seconds
The difference between the two is very significant and even though I can understand that there are some overheads in multiprocessing, it should have been faster than the sequential one right?
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or if there is a silly mistake that should be corrected.

Copying data between processes has overhead. Multiprocessing is not a "make everything faster" magic bullet -- it only helps when the cost of the overhead is outweighed by the time saved by being able to run code in parallel without the GIL. It makes no sense to try to apply it when you're doing fast operations on large amounts of data -- you pay a heavy cost to transfer all that data, when the time it would have just taken to handle the data inside your existing process is low.

...the situation when you want to use multiprocessing is when you're (1) doing a substantial amount of CPU-bound work (2) where that work isn't handled by a C library that self-parallelizes like numpy or scipy or tensorflow (3) where ideally both arguments and return values, but definitely return values, are small (in terms of data size) and fast to serialize/deserialize/transfer. Unless ALL of those conditions are met, multiprocessing is not an appropriate tool.

@AhmedAEK, reopened -- sounds like you're well-positioned to add a good answer.

Python multiprocessing.Array has lock=True by default, and any write you do will lock and unlock a mutex (and potentially flush the CPU caches), this alone accounts for 11 of the 12 seconds of the multiprocessing version, using multiprocessing.Array('i',5000000, lock=False) alone brings it down to 1 second.
Now 2 processes take equal time to 1 process to do the same work, the culprit here is that we are also comparing list to multiprocessing.Array. if we use multiprocessing.Array for the single threaded version too we get
0.8543 1 process, list
1.2004 1 process, Array
0.8488 2 process, Array

multiprocessin.Array is slower than list because list stores pointers to python integer objects, while Array has to unbox this object to obtain the underlying integer value and write it to the C array, remember python integers have infinite precision, matter of fact if you replace multiprocessing.Array with array.array, you will get an overflow exception ! the data that was written to the multiprocessing.Array is not even correct.
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker1(nums, v1):
    for i in range(nums):
        v1[i] = i * i


def worker2(nums, v2):
    for i in range(nums):
        v2[i] = i * i * i

def one_process_list():
    v1 = [0] * 5000000
    v2 = [0] * 5000000

    def worker1(nums):
        for i in range(nums):
            v1[i] = i * i

    def worker2(nums):
        for i in range(nums):
            v2[i] = i * i * i

    start = time.time()
    worker1(5000000)
    worker2(5000000)
    end = time.time()

    print(f"{end-start:.4} 1 process, list")

def one_process_array():
    v1 = multiprocessing.Array('i', 5000000, lock=False)
    v2 = multiprocessing.Array('i', 5000000, lock=False)
    
    start = time.time()
    worker1(5000000, v1)
    worker2(5000000, v2)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"{end - start:.4} 1 process, Array")

def two_process_array():
    v1 = multiprocessing.Array('i', 5000000, lock=False)
    v2 = multiprocessing.Array('i', 5000000, lock=False)

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1, args=(5000000, v1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2, args=(5000000, v2))

    start = time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    end = time.time()

    print(f"{end - start:.4} 2 process, Array")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    one_process_list()
    one_process_array()
    two_process_array()


One way around this boxing is wrapping the shared_memory in numpy array, see Sharing contiguous numpy arrays between processes in python, this way you can do operations directly in C without boxing.
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
import numpy as np

def worker_numpy(nums, v1_raw):
    v1 = np.frombuffer(v1_raw, dtype=np.int32)
    v1[:] = np.arange(nums) ** 2 # iterates a 40 MB array 3 times !

def two_process_numpy():
    my_dtype = np.int32

    def create_shared_array(size, dtype=np.int32):
        dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
        if dtype.isbuiltin and dtype.char in 'bBhHiIlLfd':
            typecode = dtype.char
        else:
            typecode, size = 'B', size * dtype.itemsize

        return RawArray(typecode, size)

    v1 = create_shared_array(5000000, dtype=my_dtype)
    v2 = create_shared_array(5000000, dtype=my_dtype)

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_numpy, args=(5000000, v1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_numpy, args=(5000000, v2))

    start = time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    end = time.time()

    print(f"{end - start:.4} 2 process, numpy")

0.8543 1 process, list
1.2004 1 process, Array
0.8488 2 process, Array
0.2774 2 process, numpy
0.0543 1 process, numpy

with numpy the entire time is actually wasted spawning the 2 extra processes, note that you may get different timing on linux where the cost of fork is less than the cost of spawn on windows, but the relative ordering won't change, also with numpy, since the GIL is dropped, we can use multithreading instead to parallelize our code.

Note 0.2 seconds seems pretty huge for spawning only 2 python processes. The overhead is probably something else like the initialization done in each processes (like the import lines)
